# I'm looking for a VBA code to copy text in the active slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, slide

Very basic question : I'm currently trying to get an action button to copy to clipboard a given text. 
At the moment, It's working with :

```
Sub CopyPasteButton()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    .Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy

End With
End Sub
```

ActivePresentation.Slides(1) being the slide number in which I'm looking for the macro to work, and .Shapes(5) the fifth shape of the page in which is contained the text.
Problem is I'm duplicating this sub for each slide on which I'd want this function to work, and I have a lot of slides. Also, when I add a slide, everything has to be manually re-written in the module.

I'm willing to get on single macro that would work for every slide, I was thinking of using this tiny bit of code I found on the web, but can't wrap my noob head around it :

```
Dim diapo As Slide
Set diapo = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your target shape is always the 5th one. you can create a shape and assign this macro. you can copy and paste the shape to any slide.

```
Sub CopyPasteButton()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    'current slide where your button is
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

    'assuming that your target shape is always the 5th one
    Set shp = sld.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
End Sub
```

Though, I would suggest that you give your target shape/text a name in the selection pane. It would be much easier and your code should look like this:

```
Sub CopyPasteButton()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    'current slide where your button is
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

    'If you have a specific name for your target 
    Set shp = sld.Shapes("NameOfYourShape").TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow thanks Louie O! I have learned a lot and will try this out next monday morning : will keep you posted, thanks you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a compile error (expected function or variable)...

Comment: Well it's the only bit of code I've got, so I've basically copy/pasted the second bit of code and gave a specific name for my target... Also, it might help but "Sub CopyPasteButton()" is highlighted in yellow and the last ".Copy" is highlighted in blue. (Thank you for your help Louie O!)

Comment: Hey Louie O, got any idea on how I could challenge that issue ?